# How can I copy a Google Chrome installation from one user to another (or all) user/s

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, installation, user-accounts

I downloaded and installed Google Chrome on a local user on Windows XP.

I *now* know that Chrome needs to be installed for each user (unless you install using a [pack](http://pack.google.com/intl/en/pack_installer.html)). Unfortunately it is installed under a user I cant use at the office.

Add to that the fact that the downloading of exe files is blocked at the office. Is there a way to 'copy' or 'move' the installation of Chrome from one user to another?

**EDIT**: *for clarity... I have Chrome installed under a local (this machine) user. I can't use that user in the office as I need to be connected to the domain. I would like to move (or copy) the installation to another user.*

Comment: Ok you want a portable version of Chrome

Comment: the installation (so you can run the browser as the other user) or the profile (so the other user gets all the same settings, bookmarks, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

reinstall chrome using the option "install for all users" (not each user). You will have to use the google installer/updater to do this however, as the chrome install doesn't allow this choice.

edit> I have to do this for all of the machines on the network here, because normal user accounts aren't permitted to install software, only the admin accounts are: and originally I couldn't figure out why, when installed by the admin, it wasn't able to be used by the users.

Answer (score 0):

To sync it to several computers just copy the entire User Data folder and paste it on the same location across the computers.

Make a copy of the User Data\Default directory (for example, copy it to 'Default Backup' in the same location). The location depends on your operating system:

- Windows XP: \Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
- Windows Vista: \Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Then get [a portable version of Chrome](http://lifehacker.com/5045439/portable-chrome-puts-chrome-on-your-thumb-drive) where you copy your Home version into.

You can use that version at your work without having to install anything

Comment: I'v tried this. When I run the chrome.exe nothing happens. By nothing I mean nothing, no hourglass, no process on the task manager, nothing.

Comment: Do you have Chrome installed for each user?

Comment: No. Perhaps I was not clear enough in the question. I have Chrome installed under a local (this machine) user. I can't use that user in the office as I need to be connected to the domain. I would like to move (or copy) the installation to another user.

Comment: Ron, if you want to make your question clearer, just edit it.  People are more likely to see your clarification in the question itself than down in the comments of a particular answer.